# ValueAxis can't change Locale

Tags: java, locale, jfreechart

I've a problem with JFreeChart locale. I created a BarChart3D but I need to change the locale of the RangeAxis.

When I retrive it from the plot i receive a ValueAxis and I can't change the locale inside it.

How can I change the locale inside it?

Is possible to change the locale of all JFreeChart?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve.  In general, JFreeChart will use the default locale settings provided by the Java runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the answer is much simpler than it seems.

I downloaded the source of JFreeChart and i saw that ValueAxis is an abstract class.
Inside the BarChart3D instantiation the axis are instantiated with NumberAxis3d superclass that extends NumberAxis that in turn extends ValueAxis.

NumberAxis can override the format provided by the Java runtime Locale with the metod setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat).